# Show $(1,1)$ tensor acts as a map from vectors to vectors

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

In Sean Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry [book](https://www.docdroid.net/wszeaIJ/sean-carroll-spacetime-and-geometry-an-introduction-to-general-relativity-pearson-education-limited-2014-pdf), pg. 22, it was stated that a (1,1) tensor acts as a map from vectors to vectors:
$${T^\mu}_\nu: V^\nu\rightarrow {T^\mu}_\nu V^\nu.$$

I tried showing this myself by considering the action of the $(1,1)$ tensor $T$ on a vector $V$:
$$T(0,V)={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu\otimes e^\nu(0,V),$$
where $e_\mu$ and $e^\nu$ are the basis vectors for the vector space and the dual vector space respectively.

I then proceed on to get
$$\begin{equation}
T(0,V)={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu(0)\times e^\nu(V) \\={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu(0)\times e^\nu(V^\rho e_\rho)\\={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu(0)\times V^\rho e^\nu( e_\rho)\\={T^\mu}_\nu e_\mu(0)\times V^\rho \delta^\nu_\rho\\={T^\mu}_\nu \times0\times V^\nu\\=0
\end{equation}$$
where I used $e_\mu(e^\rho)=\delta^\rho_\mu$ so $e_\mu(0)=0$.

The result is clearly not corret. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are yuou evaluating it on $(0, V)$ and not on $V$?

Comment: @PeterFranek Can you explicitly show what you mean by evaluating on $V$? What I learned is that a rank 2 tensor takes two arguments and produce a number.

Comment: @TaeNyFan you are right, you take two arguments - but remember the result you get is linearly dependent on *both* variables, so if one of your variables is 0, the answer will also be zero. Another way of thinking about the question is to think of dual vectors as row vectors, and normal vectors as column vectors. Then a (1,1)-tensor is just an $n\times n$ matrix (so that $T(x^{\perp},y)=x^{\perp} M y$), but then we all know an $n\times n$ matrix is just a map from $V$ to $V$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think there is some confucion here. First of all, if you admit that $T$ is a map $V\to V$, then the computation is very simple: in coordinates, $T(V)$ would be computed as
$$
(T^\mu_{\,\,\,\nu} e_\mu\otimes e^{\nu}) (V^{\mu'} e_{\mu'}) = 
T^\mu_{\,\,\,\nu}  V^\nu e_\mu
$$ (exploiting $e^\nu e_{\mu'} = \delta_{\nu \mu'}$).
That means, the $\mu$-th component of the resulting vector is $T^\mu_{\,\,\,\nu} V^\nu$. In coordinates, i'ts just matrix multiplication.

Formally, if you consider $T$ as a $(1,1)$-tensor, you can think of it as a map $V\otimes V^*\to \mathbb{C}$ (or, if you want, a bilinear map $V\times V^*\to\mathbb{C}$). So then, for any $e^{\mu}\in V^*$ (which is in fact the $\mu$-th coordinate), you get that $T(V \otimes e^\mu)$ (or, if you want, $T(V, e^\mu)$) is indeed the number that is the $\mu$-th coordinate of the vector before. So it's the complex number $T^\mu_{\,\,\,\nu}  V^\nu$.

Maybe this helps: there are natural identifications of these 3 spaces:

1. Bilinear maps $X\times V^*\to \mathbb{C}$
2. Linear maps $X\otimes V^*\to \mathbb{C}$
3. Linear maps $X\to V$.

Comment: That makes sense! So instead of $T(0,V)$, the author actually meant $T(e^\mu,V)$.

Comment: Might be. The $0$ indeed looks strange.